# JProfiler window non-visible after the start

Tags: jprofiler

After start of JProfiler 7.2.2 - I don't see main window. I use JProfiler in Windows 7 and continue see process in task manager and as an active button in launch bar without any errors, but window is hidden for me.

Environment:

- JProfiler 7.2.2 with included JRE
- Windows 7 x64
- Java 1.6.0_30 installed on machine

What I have already tried:

- Re-installed JProfiler (from older to the latest 7.x version)
- Re-started OS
- Tried to start it in evaluation mode

Except obvious question "how to fix it?", there are more ones that can help me to resolve issue on my side:

1. How to enable logging for JProfiler and where I can access these logs?
2. What other instruments JProfiler provides for analysis of its behavior?

There is a stacktrace from JProfiler process:

```
2013-02-07 13:58:42
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode):

"jprofiler_ius" prio=6 tid=0x000000000d868000 nid=0x1870 runnable [0x000000001227f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
    - locked <0x00000000e41af968> (a java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000e41af968> (a java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000a1501b20> (a java.net.DatagramPacket)
    - locked <0x00000000e41af920> (a java.net.MulticastSocket)
    at com.ejt.framework.e.u.run(ejt:98)

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000d8b9800 nid=0x2498 waiting on condition [0x000000000fd7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e3fb8440> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x000000000d457000 nid=0x22c4 waiting on condition [0x000000000ebad000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000a0592e58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.ejt.framework.gui.at.setVisible(ejt:84)
    at com.ejt.framework.gui.fu.setVisible(ejt:82)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.g.g.setVisible(ejt:42)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.d.h.bk(ejt:406)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.d.h.bg(ejt:324)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.t.run(ejt:948)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.cb.a(ejt:423)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.b(ejt:944)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.a(ejt:720)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.a(ejt:55)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.ae.run(ejt:654)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000d46d800 nid=0x448 runnable [0x000000000e9af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=6 tid=0x000000000d218800 nid=0x1dac in Object.wait() [0x000000000e7af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e41c6ca0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000e41c6ca0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000d487000 nid=0x2180 in Object.wait() [0x000000000e5af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e4014c40> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000e4014c40> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Exe4JStartupThread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000c561800 nid=0x2094 waiting on condition [0x000000000cb1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.exe4j.Controller$StartupThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000a7ea000 nid=0x203c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000a7e9000 nid=0x2074 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000a7dc000 nid=0x2514 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000a7db000 nid=0x1f80 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000a7d4000 nid=0x10f8 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x0000000002078800 nid=0x21c8 in Object.wait() [0x000000000bc1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000a0d8e088> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000a0d8e088> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000002072000 nid=0x2708 in Object.wait() [0x000000000ba1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000a0d8dbb8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000a0d8dbb8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001e6f000 nid=0x960 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x000000000a752800 nid=0x24f8 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001fc6000 nid=0x21cc runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001fc8000 nid=0x964 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001fc9800 nid=0x1b74 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000001fcb000 nid=0x1f34 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x000000000a802800 nid=0x1db0 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 859
```

Comment: Please check the file %TEMP%/jprofiler_error.log. What are the contents of it?

Comment: It looks that I don't have jprofiler_error.log in this location. Can I force its creation? (I checked %TEMP% location via "echo %TEMP%" command (without quotes) in command line).

Comment: Just realized that it could be a situation which JProfiler doesn't handle as an error. Ingo, does JProfiler creates jprofiler_error.log on start-up or on the first occurred error?

Comment: It creates it on the first output to stderr. But if no window is shown, it must hang somewhere. Please use the "jps" utility from the JRE to get the process ID and the "jstack" utility to get the current stack trace.

Comment: Added stack trace in description.

Comment: The stack trace is fine, and you should see the Quick start dialog at this point. Are you sure that the window is not hidden somewhere?

Comment: I see start dialog (both window with loading process and choosing of license type) but I don't see main window after that.

Answer (score 0):

For now I see only one workaround - use 6.2.4 version of JProfiler which works good in my environment.

Waiting for JProfiler 7.2.3+ to check behavior.